# Problem with c++ program with dynamic memory, has memory leaks, dynamic array of object pointers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am writing a program for adding points to a polygon class here is the code below. I am getting memory leaks and am completely lost. Many thanks!

UPDATE: maybe is there an alternative to memcpy??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

struct Coordinate {
    int x, y;

    Coordinate () : x(), y() {}
    Coordinate (int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

class Polygon {
    int points;
    Coordinate** coordinates;

public:

    Polygon (int _points) {
        points = _points;
        coordinates = new Coordinate*[points+1];
    }

    ~Polygon () {

        for (int i = 0; i <=points; i++){
            delete coordinates[i];
        }
        delete [] coordinates;

    }

    void putPoint (Coordinate ** pts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++) {
            memcpy(&coordinates[i], &pts[i%points], sizeof(coordinates[i]));
        }
    }

};

int main () {

    Coordinate q1 = {0,0};
    Coordinate q2 = {0,2};
    Coordinate q3 = {2,2};
    Coordinate q4 = {2,0};


    Coordinate* quadPts[4] = {&q1, &q2, &q3, &q4};
    Polygon * quad = new Polygon(4);

    quad->putPoint(quadPts);
}
```

error message

==20066==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x7fd18ba55947 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10f947)

Indirect leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x7fd18ba55b47 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10fb47)

Comment: Where do you delete `quad`

Comment: Isn't the destructor also deleting memory that is on the stack and not newed ? The whole idea of using memcpy seems bad !

Comment: Does the destructor not take care of that??

Comment: The destructor never gets called for `quad`

Comment: You never delete `quad`, so it leaks. Anyway, don't use `new` or `delete`. Avoid dynamic allocation as much as possible, and if you can't avoid it, prefer smart pointers and containers over raw pointers. `coordinates` should be a `std::vector<Coordinate>`, for example.

Comment: Uh, in polygon, there are problems. You allocate an array of coordinate pointers, never set those pointers to a valid value (nullptr or address of an allocated Coordinate), and in the destructor you attempt to call delete on all these wild pointers. Now calling delete is a good thing - once you get everything else right.

Comment: In Polygon::putPoint, your memcpy is off. Perhaps the worst thing there is that you don't have a valid destination to copy to. Once you straighten things out, you probably won't need memcopy anyway. Side note: there are restrictions on when you can use memcpy in C++ and it isn't used much.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to put the addresses of local variables (not dynamically allocated) in a Polygon, but are designing Polygon to hold dynamically allocated objects. You can't do that, you need to be consistent.  Good luck.

Comment: @artemis122353 [Why make things much harder than they should be?](https://godbolt.org/z/1367M3Ksx).   There are no calls to `memset`, `memcpy`, no `**`, no calls to `new[]`, no calls to `delete[]`, and no memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, your `Coordinate` struct does not need to be dynamically allocated like that. It's small, trivially copyable, has value semantics, and has no virtual members. You gain nothing by using pointers for those.

Second up, dynamic arrays are a pain to use. You should *always* use a container instead, preferably `std::vector` since it has the same general characteristics.

Finally, while `memcpy` works fine here for `Coordinate` because it's trivially copyable, it's a bad idea in C++ to use it to copy objects, because the moment you use it for something a bit more complicated than that, you end up with undefined behaviour. Really, `memcpy` should only be used for byte buffers.

Putting all of that together, here's a simplified version:

```
#include <vector>

struct Coordinate {
    int x, y;

    Coordinate () : x(), y() {}
    Coordinate (int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};


int main () {    
    Coordinate q1 = {0,0};
    Coordinate q2 = {0,2};
    Coordinate q3 = {2,2};
    Coordinate q4 = {2,0};

    std::vector<Coordinate> quad = { q1, q2, q3, q4 };
}
```

That's it. Of course, it's not exactly the same: I got rid of `Polygon` and used a vector directly, because it was unnecessary with your current use case. Feel free to wrap it into a class, if you want.

The point here is that most of your code was basically recreating standard library facilities, but poorly. Once you start thinking about what's already available, a lot of the complexity disappears.